# Align an image on the right side

Tags: php, html, css, gridview, yii

My code is,

```
<h4>
    <span class="icon16 icon-table"></span>
    <?php echo "PO Line";?>
    <?php echo CHtml::button(' ', array('class'=>'save-grid', 'onclick'=>'orderline()',));?>
    <a href="#" class="new-grid-" id="add-row" title="<?php echo  'Add Grid Row'; ?>"></a>
</h4>
```

The PO line is aligned on left side...The anchor tag belongs to a grid structure and I floated it right.
Now, I want the button to be on the left side of anchor tag...
(I cannot use margin-left since I want the same structure for different screen resolution).
Any solution???

Comment: create a fiddle at least

Comment: I want like this,
PO line    button <a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem. I used media queries to get the answer. I have added a sample for your reference...

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 1600px) {
.save-grid
  {
   margin-left: 1230px; 
  }         
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 1280px) {
.save-grid
  {
   margin-left: 485px;  
  }         
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use margin-left with `%` instead of `px`?

```
margin-left: 10%;
```

You can then maintain the same analogy across various sizes, as stated in your description.

Comment: please add a fiddle or some code on your post so we can troubleshoot better